# Port 8080 already being used by "SYSTEM"

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, localhost

apache tomcat is not working on port 8080. I tried to figure out what program is running on port 8080 with the netstat command

```
**C:\Users\SGaiks>netstat -aon | find ":8080"

  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4**
```

the program having PID 4 is running on port 8080, so I checked what program is having PID 4 in the task manager  and I get SYSTEM (here are the details since I cannot post screenshots)

```
Name :- SYSTEM
PID :- 4
Status :- Running
Username:- SYSTEM
CPU :- 01
Memory :- 88k
Description :- NT Kernal & System
```

what does this actually mean?
how do i disable the program that is using port 8080?

I have seen many similar questions asked but that didn't help.

(dont know if doing this is right) --> I also changed the port to some random port (localhost:2200) to run tomcat on localhost and it successfully runs. but I want it to run on **localhost:8080**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to open a browser and go to `http://localhost:8080`. If you're lucky, you have another server running and it'll serve a page. Otherwise, I'll try to dig more to help you.

**EDIT 1** : The server seems to answer (even if the requested resource wasn't found), so you should have another server running. Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284285 for troubleshooting HTTP connexion problems, and give us the result

Comment: it just gives an error message Not Found

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: Then you have a server running, otherwise you would have gotten "Unable to connect to the server" (or similar). I guess you're using windows, so maybe an IIS server ?

Comment: I don't find the IIS manager on my system. I guess my machine doesn't have it.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check that link, it might help you

Comment: Sorry this stuff is really new to me. I went to the link that you provided to me and downloaded wfetch but i am having problem in using it. i also downloaded iis 6.0 but the installation couldnt be completed because my system isnt supporting it.

Comment: What i want to know is.. Is it fine using localhost:2200 instead of loacalhost:8080 because it seems that tomcat is working perfectly fine on localhost:2200?

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly fine. You could use 8081 too for exemple. Just avoid reserved ports like 21, 22, etc. Possible choices would be 80 et 443 too for HTTP and HTTPS. Good luck !

Comment: Tried it, in my case it turned out to be Jenkins server running locally on port 8080. Killed Jenkins and it worked fine.

Comment: Viewing the headers provided from the server might tell you more. In my case the port 8080 was allocated to PID 4 - SYSTEM, and was returning a 404. But when I looked at the headers I saw "x-myob-webapiexception: V1.0", and worked out it was the AccountRight connector.

Comment: HP Display Manager it was. Nice! Now the question about how to configure that differently...

Answer (score 1):

Issue was found:
For some reason windows Media Server was running in IIS
Server stoped.
Port 8080 is now OK and available to my app.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `netstat` was unable to show the owning process even from an elevated command prompt.

As it turns out, the port was used by `OracleXETNSListener` which was running under `Local System`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into this issue try running `netsh http show servicestate` and looking at *registered URLs* or *Logging information*.....my issue was I had a WCF service running as a windows service. [Original Credit - pazadev](https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80)

Answer (score 0):

I simply Stopped IIS Manager and it worked which freed 8080 port to be picked by IISExpress

Answer (score 0):

This is very probable, that Tomcat or another Apache application is switched on autoloading when you start your PC. Please check list of autoloadings and switch off unnesessary applications

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).